# Why can't I give more than 500 bounties per question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

What's the reason you can't give more than 500+ bounties per question?

Is this little amount good enough to motivate experts in some particular field to give some nice answers?

I don't understand the nature of this limitation; it seems quite arbitrary. Let's say I do really want to get a good complete answer from some expert in some particular field, what's the best way to motivate them to put some effort on it? Of course, money is out of the game.

Comment: @Gimby Fair enough, I've edited my question to get rid of that constraint

Comment: Besides that, say you dish out a bounty of 2k rep. If someone with 1 rep gets it because they write one spectacular answer, they instantly gain a whole lot of site privileges.

Comment: @Gimby Yeah, and obviously if I'm offering a bounty of 2k I'll make sure my question won't be trivial enough to be answered in few minutes, also with such high bounties the limitation of 7 days should be modulated. Why giving the same ammount of days to a bounty of +50 than a bounty of +2000

Comment: @BPL And while you say that _"I'll make sure my question won't be trivial enough to be answered in few minutes,"_ Who's to make sure that other people's questions aren't "trivial"? And what might be trivial to you can be the hardest thing for others.

Comment: The title reads like you want to be able to set a bounty on a question 500 different times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, people with large amounts of reputation care very little about increasing that number. They aren't here answering questions to earn reputation; they're here because they either enjoy helping people, they enjoy the challenge of answering questions, or they are hoping to learn something new. Often, it is all of the above.

Therefore, it doesn't much matter whether you're offering them 100, 500, or 1000 points as a bounty. If your question is interesting to them, and it is something that they can answer, they will answer it. If not, there's no amount of reputation that will entice them. Even if you offer 50,000 points, you aren't going to convince me to go learn Python just so I can answer your Python questions. Sorry.

Users who *don't* already have more reputation than they know what to do with are naturally more likely to be incentivized by the prospect of a large bounty. However, it messes up the already-imperfect privileges system (which is based on reputation) to have a new user earn 1k or more reputation in a single blow. They will suddenly gain moderation privileges, without having learned how the site works. Keeping bounty rewards to 500 points and under helps to prevent serious problems and minimize attempts to game the system.

The *real* purpose of a bounty is to have your question listed in the site's "featured" section, where it is more likely to be seen. You "pay" in reputation for this privilege. Asking people to pay more than 500 points for this privilege is rather excessive.

Really, you shouldn't *have* to bounty questions to get them answered. If you find yourself having to offer bounties very frequently, it is a sign that your questions are problematic. They are either not very well-asked, insufficiently documented, or not very interesting, requiring you to have to "pay" people to take the time to slog through and understand them. It's okay if that happens occasionally, but at least *some* of your questions should be interesting enough to attract answers on their own merit.

Or, perhaps your questions are *way* too complicated. You mention in the comments that you'll make sure your questions aren't "trivial". That's good, but you also want to make sure that a single question isn't asking too much of a single answerer. Break complicated questions up into multiple pieces if necessary.

Comment: @Cody Gray All of them are good points which make sense, so I'll validate it. Still I don't understand the fact of one reward of +50 can be more visible than a reward of +500. Earning reputation nowadays is quite harder than it used to be 7 or 8 years ago... so it doesn't seem fair.

Comment: I've heard the claim that reputation is harder to earn now than it used to be, but I don't buy it. While it is true that people who have been around for years have accumulated a lot of reputation, and it is nearly impossible for new users to catch up to them, it is not at all true that reputation is harder to earn now than it used to be. I earn reputation at the same rate today that I did 6 years ago. And it doesn't matter that the old-timers are way out in the lead, reputation-wise, because the highest privilege level is 25k rep. After that...nothing. No one cares. @bpl

Comment: @CodyGray Well, certainly it'd be interesting to see some stats comparing how reputation was distributed at the beginning and nowadays (querying SO's db). Anyway, that's offtopic... You've already answered my question and given some valuable points I'll definitely have in mind. Thanks for your time!

Comment: +1 -- Extremely well said!